# Creating web application in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have installed SharePoint 2010 and i am trying to move the first steps in it
But i´m not able to create a simple web application
I opee the Central Administration, then select "Manage web application" under the Application Management menu
The first button in the ribbon is "New" (meaning new web application obviously), but is grey and unclickable. If i place the mouse over there it says that the control is currently disabled, because i haven´t the right permission level, i need to select an object (it isnßt the case), or the control might not work in this situation (?)
I am logged in as a farm administrator, so i wonder what is the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to run Central Administration as administrator.

**Start** -> **All Programs** -> **Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Products** -> right click on **SharePoint 2010 Central Administration** -> click on **Run as administrator**

Comment: Thanks a lot it works =) A friend told me i can also change windows user account settings, setting it to "never notify me" This way also works, and i don´t have to right click and run as administrator all the time ;)